# Resize partition after image using dd to another drive

Tags: filesystems, partition, size

I have a smaller 120GB drive which has run out of space, which I have imaged to a larger 500GB drive using:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sda4 bs=32M
```

After mounting to /R500 df shows me 100% in use which I expected

```
/dev/sda4            117214656 117214656         0 100% /R500
```

I then ran parted /dev/sda4 and it shows me:

```
Disk /dev/sda4: 460GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  460GB  460GB  reiserfs
```

I am a bit lost as to why the partition is showing the full drive size. I thought at this point I would have to resize the partition to fill the entire disk.

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: Do you still have your original 120GB drive?  If so, it's easier to use a [GParted LiveCD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), and plugin both Drives and copy from 120, paste into 460, and then resize 460.

Comment: I still have the 120GB drive in the machine, but I can't boot from a liveCD as I can't take this box offline at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had to run

> resize_reiserfs /dev/sda4

Comment: -bash: resize_reiserfs: command not found

Comment: after `apt-get install reiserfsprogs` cannot open '/dev/mmcblk1': Unknown code er3k 127

Comment: `reiserfsck --check` Do you want to run this program?[N/Yes] (note need to type Yes if you do):Yes
Failed to open the device '/dev/mmcblk1': Unknown code er3k 127

Comment: @CSQGB `resize_reiserfs` is for ReiserFS. Use `resize2fs /dev/sda4` for ext2, ext3, or ext4 FS.